# Return results grouped by table while transferring from php mysql to PDO_mysql drivers

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, pdo, cakephp-1.3

**Problem**

I'm upgrading an old cakephp 1.3 website to use cake 3.x (and beyond) but its sql calls are not returning results in the same format as they did previously.  More specifically, it appears that the cake 1.3 calls group the requested fields by their table name but cake 3 does not (see example below).

Ideally i would like the cake 3.0 results to look identical to the cake 1.3 results so that i don't have to make any significant changes to the code.

**Example**

The Query (edit: not an actual one, abridged for simplicity):

```
    $sql =  "SELECT pm.id, pmp.id  
    FROM product_models as pm  
    LEFT JOIN product_model_prices as pmp  
        ON pmp.item = pm.item  
    LIMIT 1";
```

[In cake 1.3](https://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Models.html#query):
$result = $this->ProductModel->query($sql);

```
    Array(  
          [0] => Array(  
               [pm]  => Array( [id] => 38354 ),  
               [pmp] => Array( [id] => 599874 )  
        )  
    )
```

In cake 3.0:
$result = ConnectionManager::get('default')->execute($sql)->fetchAll('assoc');

```
    [  
        (int) 0 => [ 'id' => '599874' ]  
    ]
```

*note: The missing group-by-table in cake 3 is what i'm trying to resolve.  Fixing that will also fix the vanishing id.   I should have used a simpler example.

Under the hood Cake 1.3's query() method appears to simply call something along the lines of
`$dbConnection->query($sql)`
So my guess is that this has less to do with cake and is instead being done by the mysql driver.  Cake 1.3 is using the now defunct [mysql driver](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) while cake 3 is using [PDO_mysql](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php).  To that end i've attempted to use a number of its various [fetch modes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)  but none seems to give me what i need.

I also briefly entertained the idea of switching to mysqli but that doesn't appear to be possible in cake 3+ .

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I have been where you are, and trust me when I say that in the long run you are in for a lot less pain if you accept how Cake 3 (and beyond) want to return the results (as entities). Making the change now is a bunch of short-term pain. Working around making the change is still a fair bit of short-term pain, but also a never-ending stream of long-term pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your query is that in the result set both `pm.id` and `pmp.id` will appear as `id`, and so when they are written to an associative array the second value will override the first, giving an array with just one `id` key and value. Note that this behaviour would be identical under any of the mysql, mysqli and PDO drivers. Somewhere under the hood Cake 1.3 must have been rewriting the queries to alias the columns being selected to overcome the problem. You can do something similar with your query to partially workaround the problem. I don't think you'll be able to get the exact same structure, but at least something close:

```sql
SELECT pm.id AS pm, pmp.id AS pmp
FROM product_models as pm  
LEFT JOIN product_model_prices as pmp  
     ON pmp.item = pm.item
```

This will return an array that looks like

```php
[  
    (int) 0 => [ 'pm' => '38354', 'pmp' => '599874' ]  
]
```

which at least has the same top-level structure.

Note you have a `LIMIT` clause in your query with no `ORDER BY` clause. This is essentially meaningless and there is no guarantee that running this query twice will return the same result. See [Is it safe to use LIMIT without ORDER BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34812412/is-it-safe-to-use-limit-without-order-by).

Comment: Unfortunately this solution isn't practical.  Perhaps i should have mentioned this but i stripped most of the requested fields out of this example to keep it simple; same with the LIMIT.  The actual call requests all fields and most records from both tables.  To say nothing of the hundreds of other query() calls this site uses.  And cake 1.3 isn't grouping by table because it sees my duel 'id' issue; it does that for all requests, even those without joins.  There's an example showing this if you click on the 'In cake 1.3' link above.

Comment: @Patrick One way or the other you're in for a lot of work. Either you rewrite your queries and the code that processes the results, or you change the code to use the new ORM introduced in Cake 3.0 (or better yet, migrate all the way to 5 as 3 is out of support now anyway)

Comment: @Patrick btw it's not the old MySQL driver creating this nested output, it's Cake itself. The old MySQL driver, `mysqli` and `PDO` will *all* return `[  [ 'id' => '599874' ]  ]` for that query

Comment: Time constraints being what they are i was hoping to make as few changes as necessary but if cake itself is nesting the outputs, as you say, then you're right and my code will need to be modified.  Thanks again for your support, Nick.

Comment: Asking pdo_mysql to mimic mysql's response seems reasonable but asking it to mimic cake is certainly not.  As such i feel like your comment should be the accepted answer and the answer we're commenting in is a side-addition.  Should i accept this or let you create a new answer?

Comment: @Patrick I've updated the answer to include the comment about the drivers. I think it's fairly complete now, if you feel the need to change it around slightly feel free to edit and I'll approve any change.